# Google Analytics event tracking code breaks wordpress site when added to functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics

I've added a global button via functions.php that shows on my product pages using the following code:

```
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
echo '
<div class="wsbl_line"><a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/website.com" 
title="share using Line" rel="nofollow" 
class="wp_social_bookmarking_light_a"><img src="sample-image.png" 
width="135" height="30" class="wp_social_bookmarking_light_img"></a></div>';
}
```

Upon adding the following Google Analytics event tracking code to the above code the site breaks.

```
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
echo '
<div class="wsbl_line"><a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/website.com" 
title="share using Line" rel="nofollow" 
class="wp_social_bookmarking_light_a" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'social', 'line-button-click', 'line-button');"><img src="sample-image.png" 
width="135" height="30" class="wp_social_bookmarking_light_img"></a></div>';
}
```

I've successfully tested the tracking code by putting it directly in a page

```
<a href="website.com" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'social', 'line-button-
click', 'line-button');">anchor text</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should escape the ' in the code you're trying to echo.

Comment: Do you mean the opening and close single quotes of the echo or the Google Analytics parameters?

Comment: Or use double quotes in the GA javascript code. Since you open your php echo code with a single quote it terminates at the first single quote within the echo block (and the rest is not valid PHP, so you get an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open code with single quote and use them in code you want to echo, you need to escape it, like this:

```
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
echo '
<div class="wsbl_line"><a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/website.com" 
title="share using Line" rel="nofollow" 
class="wp_social_bookmarking_light_a" onClick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', 
\'social\', \'line-button-click\', \'line-button\');"><img src="sample-
image.png" 
width="135" height="30" class="wp_social_bookmarking_light_img"></a></div>';
}
```

Even if you open echo with " doublequotes it will break since there are double quostes in code you are echoing. I advise you to use some text editor with php syntax highlighting to see where it breaks.

Try the code i gave you,
Regards